# Java programming in files , random , GUI

Tags: file, swing, random, jbutton, jlabel

I want to write a Java program that reads the data from a file and stores it in an array. And then generates a random array index and uses it to retrieve a random word from the array to display. Each time the user clicks Next button, the program chooses a new random word to be displayed. I'm trying to add buttons in frame but they won't appear on the `JFrame`. Following is the code I wrote:

```
okButton = new JButton ("OK");
Pane.add(okButton);  

nextButton = new JButton ("Next");
Pane.add(nextButton);
```

When the user enters a right answer I want a `JLabel` to appear saying `" Correct answer "`. How do I make a JLabel Appear? and when the user closes the frame all the right answers show in a `JTextArea`.
Can you please help me?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too much cluttered and vague to me, so providing perfect answer is quite not possible. Following are some useful tips you can use to solve your problem.

- read file which contains the word. See [File operations in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) and
  [How to use FileChooser?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)
- Tokenize file and create an array of words. You can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class for this
- Create a method to randomly word from the array. You can use [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class for this.

---

For the GUI part:

> *the buttons won't appear on the JFrame*

Are you adding panel containing buttons to frame properly?

> *how do I make a JLabel Appear ?*

Add that JLabel to panel/frame and repaint it.

> *when the user closes the frame all the right answers show in a
>   JTextArea*

1. Save right answers in some other array (call it answerArray).
2. Add Window listener to frame to monitor closing of frame.
3. In close method create a JDialog containing JTextArea and loop over answerArray and append string to textArea. Finally display this new JDialog.